# How do I save a layer without the transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a layer, which I would like to save as an image. See
[image]

(the image is the complete button)
When I choose the layer and choose file->save for web.. it save the image with the transparent background. I would like save the image without the background - just the image itself (which is way smaller than the full one)

How can I do it?

I am using PhotoShop CS5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Choose `Image > Trim` and tick the "Transparent Pixels" option.
- Save for Web
- If you want the full image back, choose `Edit > Step Backwards`

Answer (score 0):

You need to crop it to the image dimension first.To select the image only, in your case it is the white rectangle/button,use crop tool(C) and drag a rectangle around the image and hit enter to apply.Then file-->save for web